# Event/Time and criteria based SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I guess this is more a design pattern question than a SQL one.

In my application a user can join, can create a shop and load products in their shop (so lets say that there is a user, shop (one to one) and products (many to one with the shops).

So I want to be able to do certain things based on time and criteria (but only once) so for example if one week after joining a user has no shop I want to send an email, or 2 weeks after joining with a shop but no products send a email etc - but I only want to do it once.

Its the only running once which is doing my head in - so for example lets say I had this query

```
select * from user where joineddt < '1 week ago date'
```

And I had a script which ran every 3 hours, fires off the SQL and then does whatever event (e.g. send a email)  I then want to ensure if this script was fired again it would not pick up any users which have already been processed.  I thought of introducing a 'events' table where once the event for a user has been fired, log a entry for that event, but that again does not seem to work.  For example say I had the events table, had id, user, event

```
select * from user a
left join event b on b.user = a.id
where a.joineddt < '1 week ago date'
and b.event = 'userjoined'
and b.id is null
```

So when there is no entry in the events able for the 'userjoined' event, it will return no results...But really I want it to return the users where there is no event in event table for this 'userjoined' event?

So can anyone think of a way to do what I am suggesting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query will always return 0 rows, because if b.id is null, b.event can never be 'userjoined'.
Move the 'userjoined' criteria to the join clause.

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM user a 
LEFT JOIN event b ON (b.user = a.id AND b.event = 'userjoined') 
WHERE a.joineddt < '1 week ago date' 
AND b.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have an extra table (joins are expensive) to implement your solution. In your user table, just add two nullable date columns: 'date_joined' and 'reminded'. Make sure your application logic (which you can define into the table/database side) defaults 'date_joined' to date of joining and 'reminded' to NULL.

To pick up users needing a reminder:

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE date_joined > '1 week ago' AND reminded IS NULL
```

Make sure to fill out 'reminded' with a date once you have sent the email. That way the next run of the script will not pick it up.

Comment: The 2 events were just example, there are many events and I wish to add more as time goes on, would not want to add the columns for every type of event.  In terms of expense, it will be a offline daemon running periodically so should not have a impact.